# Iterating over 2D list using asterisk (*) operator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I saw this piece of code being used to iterate over a 2D list column-wise:

```
"""
grid: List[List(int)]
"""
for col in zip(*grid):
    ...
```

Could someone explain exactly how this works?

EDIT:

Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404681/what-does-python-zipx-do-with-asterisk?noredirect=1&lq=1) question, but not [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters) one.

I still don't understand exactly how `zip(*_)` converts rows into columns.

Comment: if `grid` looks like `[[1,2,3], [7, 8, 9]]`, then `zip(*grid)` looks like `zip([1,2,3], [7, 8, 9])`. Does it make sense why that transposes rows to columns?

Comment: This has more to do with [inverse function of zip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13635074/1586200). If the question reopens, I can write an answer. You can experiment by yourself too. Just do: `a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], print zip(*a)`. You can also read [this](https://medium.com/@happymishra66/zip-in-python-48cb4f70d013).